# Download Gradle dependency externally without gradle by name of implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management

Is there any way to download Gradle implementation .AAR files by name. For example there is an implementation written in build.gradle file say
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
Is it possible to download the .AAR library file by name 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' without Gradle. I am looking for a way to download any kind of libraries mentioned in build.gradle file of an android project.

Comment: Picasso is a JAR, not an AAR. The MVNRepository site has pages for Maven artifacts, such as [this one for Picasso 2.5.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/2.5.2). There are links to download the files associated with that artifact (such as [the JAR](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.5.2/picasso-2.5.2.jar)). However, bear in mind that this will not handle transitive dependencies, where one library depends on other libraries.

Comment: Okay I got that picasso library is a jar. Thanks for correcting. But Is there any way to change Gradle implementation name into a downloadable link? If any method works for any kind of  implementation not just picasso library?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing all this? There might be another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manually get **`.JAR`** file in your system, follow these steps:

1. Go to Maven Repository to search for any dependency.
2. Click on the version number you want to install.
3. On the details page, click the link next to **`Files`** row:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to automate something. So, I got my kind of answer which I am providing here.
I have added the implementation name in the following URL-
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
Thus the implementation name 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' can be used in the link to reach the resources as follows-
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.5.2/

The ':' and '.' is changed to '/'